# SQLAlchemy: Prevent parameter substitution during query compilation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following example code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import *
e = create_engine("sqlite://")
stmt = select([text("some_function(':x')")])
print(str(stmt.compile(e)))
```

The code prints:

```
SELECT some_function('?')
```

That is, it has treated `:x` as a parameter, which is not what I wanted.

Is it possible to prevent SQLAlchemy from searching for and substituting parameters in the statement?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Fuxi: I have an existing query and I want to limit the number of rows in a dialect-independent way. The solution `select(['*'], from_obj=text(f'({query}) x').limit(10)` works fine except when `query` contains `:something`, which SQLAlchemy substitutes with `%(something)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out a solution. Turns out (and it is given in the docstring of `text` function), colons may be escaped with `\:`. `text` will then handle them as usual colons and remove the escaping at compilation. I.e. the original example can be fixed as follows:

```
stmt = select([text("some_function(':x')".replace(':', r'\:'))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using `from_statement` as on [examples from docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) and then applying limit after?

I noticed you are using `sqlite` as your engine, that's is the most likely cause of `?` in printed query. It's defined like that in SQLAlchemy SQLite dialect (`sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py`) - `qmark`. Different dialects have it defined differently. You are after `named`. Reference:
 [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

You can try:

`from sqlalchemy.dialects import sqlite
query = stmt.compile(dialect=sqlite.dialect(paramstyle="named"))`

Comment: Firstly, `from_statement` is a property of a `Query` object, which I don't have in my case. Secondly, the `text` object will still substitute parameters, as you can see in the docs.

Comment: The `sqlite` engine is a random choice in the example for reproducibility. Other dialecs would still replace `:param` with their own parameter forms.
What I am essentially looking for is an alternative to `text` which does not do bind parameters.